# Implement location at wordpress post via custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to add a new custom hierarchical taxonomy (or 3 custom taxonomies... dependent your answer) which contain the location by: City + States&territories + Country.

for example:
   Orlando + Florida + United States
   Monroeville + Pennsylvania + United States
   Noyabrsk + Yamalo-Nenets Autonomous Okrug + Russia

In the final implementation the user can choose post (or posts list) by choosing Country (and or) states & territories (and or) City.

One more thing for my example: if the user choosing Russia as Country he won't get the option for Florida as States&territories...

Can I implement it as custom hierarchical taxonomy (or 3 custom taxonomies)?

Comment: This is not a question, this is a set of question**s**, perhaps you should ask each individual question separately? Else it's hard to understand exactly what an answer would be, since an answer to one is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes implement it as a heirarchical taxonomy. Have your countries as the top level terms, then states, then cities. Your URL structure will naturally reflect this. I would advise against /city/state/country, as it is illogical and counter intuitive, and doesn't make for a good heirarchy ( so bad SEO too ).

On your frontend, taxonomy-location.php should be your template. I'd strongly advise against using 3 dropdown lists, as it's poor UI/UX and a pain to implement. Instead look at ecommerce sites and implement the drilldown list pattern of picking a country, then picking a state on the next page, then a city on the next, letting users look on a country wide level or a state wide level or a city depending on how specific they want it.

The details of how to implement that however are beyond the scope of this question and answer, you will need to ask in another question

Comment: Thanks Tom,I'll use the hierarchical taxonomy.
In the same subject - can I import hierarchical custom taxonomy too? I know there is option to import custom taxonomy but hierarchical?? (Google didn't help me about :( )

Comment: A heirarchical taxonomy is not something different from a custom taxonomy, it's as nonsensical a question as ***"Can I feed a poodle too? I know I can feed dogs but a Poodle?"***